DLL exports same function with multiple names
When ntdll.dll is loaded in x64dbg, I see that there can be multiple symbols at the same address. For example;

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve something like this using regular msvc tools like cl.exe/link.exe. Is it safe to assume then, this functions are created with an assembler and then linked with rest of the dll?

It's likely just using a .def file, to define the exports e.g.
// example.def
LIBRARY "example"
EXPORTS
    MyFunctionAlias1 = MyFunction
    MyFunctionAlias2 = MyFunction

